# a.e.-defined integrable functions on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading the book Folland-Real Analysis. On page 54 after the proposition 2.23 it is written:

With this in mind, we shall find it more convenient to redefine $L^{1}(\mu)$ to be the set of equivalence classes of a.e.-defined integrable functions on $X$, where $f$ and $g$ are considered equivalence iff $f=g$ a.e.

I did not understand what he means by:

" a.e.-defined integrable functions on $X$"

If anyone can help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: I think the answer is the following: let us denote the domain of the function $f$ by $D(f)\subset X$.

The expression "a.e.-defined integrable functions on $X$" means that $\mu\big(X-D(f)\big)=0$ and $f$ is integrable in $D(f)$

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from Foland:

[image]

So, when Foland says that a function is defined "only" a.e. then he means that from the point of view of integration it is enough to define a function almost everywhere; that is, on null sets the functions do not have to be defined.